# Boostrap modal not loading in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I am trying to load a Bootstrap modal in Laravel but it does not appear at all. I've installed node_modules. In my `resources/assets/sass/app.scss` it has by default the following:

```
// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

This is my button :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-button" id="edit-button">Edit</button>
```

and this is my modal:

```
 <!-- Modal EDIT -->
     <div class="modal" id="edit-button" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit section</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        //model body
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it! In the `app.blade.php` file I needed to include the app.js like

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

This by default though loads a Vue.js file which just includes

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

app.js file is located in

```
resources/assets/js/app.js
```